# Use hover on div and mouseout at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouse, jquery-hover

I am working with jQuery `hover` and `mouseout` script but issue is that when I set `hover` on `div` when `mouseout` is working, `div` gets hide, and visible continuously (blinking).

How to overcome this problem?

Here is my code:

```
<style>
 .append_div{

 position: absolute;
    top: 8%;
    display: none; 
 background-color: pink;
    border-right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 30px;
    display:none;
}

</style>

<body>
  <div class="menu">
  Hover Me 

  </div>

  <div class="append_div">

  </div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<script>
  $('.menu').hover(function(){

    $(".append_div").show();
    $(".append_div").css({"width":"170px","z-index":"1078"});

});
$( ".menu" ).mouseout(function() {
  $(".append_div").hide('slow');
});
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works. The `div` is shown as long as I hover on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the cause of the problem is quickly try, you can fix that with `stop()` and `finish()` functions.

```
$(".append_div").css({"width":"170px","z-index":"1078"});

$('.menu').hover(function(){
    $( ".append_div" ).finish();
    $(".append_div").show();

});
$( ".menu" ).mouseout(function() {
    $( ".append_div" ).finish();
    $(".append_div").hide('slow');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/63dofz48/16/

or better for eyes with two slow effect

https://jsfiddle.net/63dofz48/10/

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is blinking when hover and mouseout happens quickly try to put a delay when hiding the happend_div:

```
$( ".menu" ).mouseout(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".append_div").hide('slow');
    }, 500);
});
```